# read json into R

Tags: json, r

After a couple of days struggle, I decided to ask to experts of stackoverflow.

I wanted to export this (for example) "http://www.appannie.com/app/ios/instagram/ranking/history/chart_data/?s=2010-10-06&e=2012-06-04&c=143441&f=ranks&d=iphone" into R.

So here's what I tried.

```
library(RJSONIO)
library(rjson)
library(RCurl)
appannie <- getURL("http://www.appannie.com/app/ios/instagram/ranking/history/chart_data/.json?s=2010-10-06&e=2012-06-04&c=143441&f=ranks&d=iphone")
fromJSON(appannie)
```

But this gives me an error of "No data to parse".

But i can clearly see that there is data (I can see the data from the browser).

[{"data": [[1286323200000, 70, "Initial release\n"], [1286409600000, 65, null], [1286496000000, 89, null], [1286582400000, 106, null], [1286668800000, 143, null], [1286755200000, 172, null], [1286841600000, 106, null], [1286928000000, 116, null], [1287014400000, 78, null], [1287100800000, 102, null],  ...... [1338768000000, 2, null]], "label": "Photo and Video"}]

So I tried this one.

```
fromJSON(paste(readLines('http://www.appannie.com/app/ios/instagram/ranking/history/chart_data/.json?s=2010-10-06&e=2012-06-04&c=143441&f=ranks&d=iphone'), collapse=""))
```

But this one gives me an error of "unexpected character '<'".

Can somebody give me a guidance why this is happening and how to solve this?

Comment: Well, going to [that URL](http://www.appannie.com/app/ios/instagram/ranking/history/chart_data/.json?s=2010-10-06&e=2012-06-04&c=143441&f=ranks&d=iphone) doesn't get JSON, it gets a 404 error (and therefore HTML).

Comment: Take a look at your object `appannie` - what does it have?  If it looks like `JSON`, can you please `dput(appannie)` and post it into your question.  If it does not look like `JSON`, then you have your answer ;)

Comment: @DavidRobinson I'm getting a 403 error.  Perhaps the OP has access that we do not?

Comment: oh oh my bad. I forgot that I was logged in entire time. The data can be seen when you're logged in so I clipped the data and attached it. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: You're logged in when you view it in your browser, but is the RCurl request "logged in"? Can the url request from R know and access your login from your browser? I'm guessing no...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the data you pasted:

```
  jsonRaw <- '{"data": [[1286323200000, 70, "Initial release\n"], [1286409600000, 65, null], [1286496000000, 89, null], [1286582400000, 106, null], [1286668800000, 143, null], [1286755200000, 172, null], [1286841600000, 106, null], [1286928000000, 116, null], [1287014400000, 78, null], [1287100800000, 102, null], [1338768000000, 2, null]], "label": "Photo and Video"}]'
```

Everything works fine:

```
  jsonParsed <- fromJSON(jsonRaw)
```

What is probably happening is that R does not have access to the website. 
Take a look at the output from your `RCurl` statement.  If it is not `json`-like data, then there you have your issue.

EDIT:

You state

> *"But i can clearly see that there is data (I can see the data from the browser)."*

But you are logged in, so clearly that is not the same thing as seeing it in `R`

Comment: I missed the important thing. Thank you!